# Manipulate date format in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, date, datetime

I have this datetime format output in UILabel

> datefrom.text = "2010-12-05 00:00:00"

But I want to display this date format into something simple like this

> 5 December 2010 or Dec 5, 2010

I use this code to display the date but it display the today's date which is 5 April 2017

date.swift

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"
let result = formatter.string(from:date)
datefrom.text = result
```

Any solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to first convert the string into a `Date` using a `DateFormatter` that matches the original format, then use your 2nd format to convert the `Date` into the new string.

Comment: Can you post the code in your answer ? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I convert this date format in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175256/how-can-i-convert-this-date-format-in-swift)

Comment: Obviously you need to adjust the `dateFormat` values to suit your specific needs compared to the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateFormatter` will help you do this!

Step 1: Convert your string to a date type

```
func convertStringToDate(string: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

Step 2: Convert your date to your expected format

```
func convertDateToString(date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

That's it!

```
let dateString = "2010-12-05 00:00:00"

let date = convertStringToDate(string: dateString)
let result = convertDateToString(date: date!)

datefrom.text = result
// 5 Dec 2010
```