# I tried to display date in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format in swift3 but it display nil, can you check my below code.

Tags: json, swift, date

I retrieved date from JSON service and I try to display '2017-07-18T00:00:00' date into '18-07-2017' but my below code returns nil, can you check below code.

```
let date1 = item["StartDate"] as? AnyObject //2017-07-18T00:00:00
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
 let TestDateTime = formatter.date(from: date1)
 print("zday:\(TestDateTime)")
```

Comment: You got a string `2017-07-18T00:00:00` and you are trying to parse it using format `dd.MM.yyyy`. That can't be correct. Instead, you would have to parse it using it the correct format `dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss` to a `Date` and then format it to a `String` using your format.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175256/how-can-i-convert-this-date-format-in-swift for an example.

Comment: The correct syntax is formatter.string(from: Date), not formatter.string.date(from: Date)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format of the input string when creating a `Date` object from its `String` representation. After creating the `Date` object, you can use a different date format to generate a `String` representation of the date in your desired format.

```
let date1 = item["StartDate"] as? String //2017-07-18T00:00:00
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss"
let testDateTime = formatter.date(from: date1)
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
print("zday:\(outputFormatter.string(from: testDateTime)")
```

Comment: I tried above code, it displays , "JobDescription": <p style="text-align: justify;">This is for testing position</p>, "JobPositionStatus": Open]]
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: The part before the error has nothing to do with this code. For the error, I guess you are unsafe unwrapping `date1`, don't do that, use safe unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
func convertDateFormater(_ date: String) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
formatter.string(from: Date)
```

So your code should be:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let TestDateTime = formatter.string(from: date1)
```